# .so error when i run radius server in debugging mode

Tags: debugging, shared-libraries, runtime-error, freeradius

this is an error i got when i run radius server in debugging mode **radiusd -X**.
  i checked a lot and i unable to get the logic,why it is really happend.

> root@amsys-ThinkPad-R61:/home/amsys/freeradius-server-2.2.5# radiusd -X
>   radiusd: error while loading shared libraries: libfreeradius-radius-020205.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

when i prefectly installed radius server,why i got this problem??

if anyone would aware about this, kindly give prompt response to me ,that how to get out this error.you are really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably moved the libraries after installation, and your linker path didn't include the location where you moved them to. Use `ldd -v <path to radiusd>` to show where the linker assumed the libraries were going to be located.